# Defining query to execute in expression in Textbox

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2012

I have many `TextBoxes` in my `SSRS` project. They all have expressions similar to this one:

```
="TotalListings" + STR(Sum(iif(Fields!STAT_NAME.Value = "TotalListings", 
Int(Fields!VALUE.Value), 0), "MLS"))
```

Is it possible to create a table with StatName and associated query to be executed, so that query will be executed from this table depending what is in StatName?

For example: create such table:
[image]

So, since expression structure is as following: `=[StatName]+[QueryResult]`, I want to write into Expression just StatName (i.e. TotalListings), and the other part (query result) will be calculated from corresponding query in table.

If this is not possible, why?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using a similar expression to the expression you used. But the SSRS-way to do this is to create a StatName row group in the tablix and just use `SUM(Fields!Value.Value)` in the Query column.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, but how to make a row group to TextBox. I do that in case I will want to change query in the future. If you know the way of doing so, could you please exemplify this?

Comment: Did not you state in your question that you wanted to create a **table**? If I understand your question what you need is to calculate the SUM even if the STATNAME value is dynamic which will leave the hardcoded expression unuseful.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, I want to create SQL table on backend, so that to execute related query in Query column for each corresponding StatName stated in TextBox and retrieve its value into that same textbox

Comment: Basically I want expression to be similar to ="TotalListings"+exec(exec(select Query from QUERIES where StatName = 'TotalListings'))

Comment: I don't understand the need for creating a table in the backend even more if you are going to hardcode TotalListings. I'd create a tablix and set a row group using StatName, if you don't want to it looks like a table you can hide the borders. Share data sample and your expected result in the report to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, I'll have many such textboxes, I would like to be able to see easily what query results are actually being retrieved, and if needed to change query by simple update, without going into Visual Studio, and then find necessary Textbox, and then update it, and then deploy it.